# Webclient 401 Unauthorized

Tags: java, spring-boot, http-status-code-401, spring-webclient

I am using WebClient to access Endpoints, which are simple echo Endpoints, to test the connection.
Everytime I am calling the WebClient get method I get a 401 error, but when I try to access the Endpoints with Swagger with the same credentials it works without any problems. I'm pretty sure I forgot something simple, but looking at different tutorials it seems like I've done everything correctly.

My Code:

```
try{
WebClient webClient = WebClient
            .builder()
                .baseUrl("http://localhost:8030")
                .defaultHeaders(headers -> headers.setBasicAuth("admin","adminPassword"))
            .build();

String getValue = webClient.get()
                    .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder
                            .path("/echo")
                            .queryParam("inputString", "{input}")
                            .build("get test"))
                    .retrieve()
                    .bodyToMono(String.class)
                    .block();
            System.out.println(getValue);
}catch (WebClientResponseException ex){
            System.out.println("WebClientResponseException code: " + ex.getStatusCode() +"\n"+"WebClientResponseMessage: " + ex.getResponseBodyAsString());
            throw ex;
        }
```

This is the printed error I get:

```
WebClientResponseException code: 401 UNAUTHORIZED
WebClientResponseMessage: <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <title>401 Unauthorized</title>
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>401 Unauthorized</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Even I am facing similar issue, could you please let me know what is the fix?, if you have already fixed it.